# OpenSSL Header Version != OpenSSL Library Version affecting HTTP/2 for APNS

Tags: php, apache-2.4, openssl, curl

i have this weird combo on my openSSL on WAMP.

My windows command prompt `openssl version` returns the library version -> OpenSSL 1.0.2h 3 May 2016

while my php curl call -> `echo "openssl version text: " . OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT . "\n";` returns the header version: openssl version text: OpenSSL 1.0.1t 3 May 2016

I wonder how can i updated the OpenSSL Header version as i need 1.0.2 in order for the APNS to work as i'm still getting

HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 504f5354202f332f6465766963652f613433646466376235

**i'm using Windows server 2008
Windows NT OMEGA 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1) AMD64**

**WAMP Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) 
Apache showing Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.16 but obviously not using it.**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that PHP is linked to an older version of the library?  If you installed all those with the system's package/update manager, then you may want to report this as a bug in their distribution.